# How to iterate through object containing other object types in C#

Tags: c#

(Complete noob here, appologies if I'm unclear!) I have been using Riot Games' API to get information of a players stats on specific characters in a game. I used Json2CSharp in order to create the following data object.

```
public class Data
        {
            public Aatrox Aatrox { get; set; }
            public Ahri Ahri { get; set; }
            public Akali Akali { get; set; }
            public Alistar Alistar { get; set; }
            public Amumu Amumu { get; set; }
            public Anivia Anivia { get; set; }
            public Annie Annie { get; set; }
            public Ashe Ashe { get; set; }
            public AurelionSol AurelionSol { get; set; }
            public Azir Azir { get; set; }
            public Bard Bard { get; set; }
            public Blitzcrank Blitzcrank { get; set; }
            public Brand Brand { get; set; }
            public Braum Braum { get; set; }
            public Caitlyn Caitlyn { get; set; }
            public Camille Camille { get; set; }
            public Cassiopeia Cassiopeia { get; set; }
            public Chogath Chogath { get; set; }
            public Corki Corki { get; set; }
            public Darius Darius { get; set; }
            public Diana Diana { get; set; }
            public Draven Draven { get; set; }
            public DrMundo DrMundo { get; set; }
            public Ekko Ekko { get; set; }
            public Elise Elise { get; set; }
            public Evelynn Evelynn { get; set; }
            public Ezreal Ezreal { get; set; }
            public FiddleSticks FiddleSticks { get; set; }
            public Fiora Fiora { get; set; }
            public Fizz Fizz { get; set; }
            public Galio Galio { get; set; }
            public Gangplank Gangplank { get; set; }
            public Garen Garen { get; set; }
            public Gnar Gnar { get; set; }
            public Gragas Gragas { get; set; }
            public Graves Graves { get; set; }
            public Hecarim Hecarim { get; set; }
            public Heimerdinger Heimerdinger { get; set; }
            public Illaoi Illaoi { get; set; }
            public Irelia Irelia { get; set; }
            public Ivern Ivern { get; set; }
            public Janna Janna { get; set; }
            public JarvanIV JarvanIV { get; set; }
            public Jax Jax { get; set; }
            public Jayce Jayce { get; set; }
            public Jhin Jhin { get; set; }
            public Jinx Jinx { get; set; }
            public Kalista Kalista { get; set; }
            public Karma Karma { get; set; }
            public Karthus Karthus { get; set; }
            public Kassadin Kassadin { get; set; }
            public Katarina Katarina { get; set; }
            public Kayle Kayle { get; set; }
            public Kennen Kennen { get; set; }
            public Khazix Khazix { get; set; }
            public Kindred Kindred { get; set; }
            public Kled Kled { get; set; }
            public KogMaw KogMaw { get; set; }
            public Leblanc Leblanc { get; set; }
            public LeeSin LeeSin { get; set; }
            public Leona Leona { get; set; }
            public Lissandra Lissandra { get; set; }
            public Lucian Lucian { get; set; }
            public Lulu Lulu { get; set; }
            public Lux Lux { get; set; }
            public Malphite Malphite { get; set; }
            public Malzahar Malzahar { get; set; }
            public Maokai Maokai { get; set; }
            public MasterYi MasterYi { get; set; }
            public MissFortune MissFortune { get; set; }
            public MonkeyKing MonkeyKing { get; set; }
            public Mordekaiser Mordekaiser { get; set; }
            public Morgana Morgana { get; set; }
            public Nami Nami { get; set; }
            public Nasus Nasus { get; set; }
            public Nautilus Nautilus { get; set; }
            public Nidalee Nidalee { get; set; }
            public Nocturne Nocturne { get; set; }
            public Nunu Nunu { get; set; }
            public Olaf Olaf { get; set; }
            public Orianna Orianna { get; set; }
            public Pantheon Pantheon { get; set; }
            public Poppy Poppy { get; set; }
            public Quinn Quinn { get; set; }
            public Rammus Rammus { get; set; }
            public RekSai RekSai { get; set; }
            public Renekton Renekton { get; set; }
            public Rengar Rengar { get; set; }
            public Riven Riven { get; set; }
            public Rumble Rumble { get; set; }
            public Ryze Ryze { get; set; }
            public Sejuani Sejuani { get; set; }
            public Shaco Shaco { get; set; }
            public Shen Shen { get; set; }
            public Shyvana Shyvana { get; set; }
            public Singed Singed { get; set; }
            public Sion Sion { get; set; }
            public Sivir Sivir { get; set; }
            public Skarner Skarner { get; set; }
            public Sona Sona { get; set; }
            public Soraka Soraka { get; set; }
            public Swain Swain { get; set; }
            public Syndra Syndra { get; set; }
            public TahmKench TahmKench { get; set; }
            public Taliyah Taliyah { get; set; }
            public Talon Talon { get; set; }
            public Taric Taric { get; set; }
            public Teemo Teemo { get; set; }
            public Thresh Thresh { get; set; }
            public Tristana Tristana { get; set; }
            public Trundle Trundle { get; set; }
            public Tryndamere Tryndamere { get; set; }
            public TwistedFate TwistedFate { get; set; }
            public Twitch Twitch { get; set; }
            public Udyr Udyr { get; set; }
            public Urgot Urgot { get; set; }
            public Varus Varus { get; set; }
            public Vayne Vayne { get; set; }
            public Veigar Veigar { get; set; }
            public Velkoz Velkoz { get; set; }
            public Vi Vi { get; set; }
            public Viktor Viktor { get; set; }
            public Vladimir Vladimir { get; set; }
            public Volibear Volibear { get; set; }
            public Warwick Warwick { get; set; }
            public Xerath Xerath { get; set; }
            public XinZhao XinZhao { get; set; }
            public Yasuo Yasuo { get; set; }
            public Yorick Yorick { get; set; }
            public Zac Zac { get; set; }
            public Zed Zed { get; set; }
            public Ziggs Ziggs { get; set; }
            public Zilean Zilean { get; set; }
            public Zyra Zyra { get; set; }

        }
```

each champion's respective object looking like the below:

```
public class Ziggs
        {
            public string version { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string key { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string blurb { get; set; }
            public Info132 info { get; set; }
            public Image132 image { get; set; }
            public List<string> tags { get; set; }
            public string partype { get; set; }
            public Stats132 stats { get; set; }
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is get at the ID for each champion, and have been trying with the for loop below:

```
foreach (var champion in ChampionData.data.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(champion.id);
            }
```

This however does not seem to allow me to access the ID, nor any of the other properties of the objects. I have been able to access the values calling them indervisually, however cannot figure out how I can iterate through the object.

Any advise would be really appreciated!

Edit: Here is where I'm getting the Json from: http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json

Comment: "each champion's respective object looking like the below"; does that mean each of these classes are exactly the same?

Comment: If each champion is described by the exact same properties, then you shouldn't have a different class for each one. You should have a `Champion` class, then you can store information in an appropriate data structure (such as `List<Champion>`) and iterate over the list.

Comment: Depending on the JSON structure, and it's suggested by the code that you've shown, you might need a `Dictionary<string, Champion>`. I'm guessing it looks like  `{ "Aatrox": {...}, ...}`

Comment: Can you provide the original JSON (or a representative part)?

Comment: @Stefan Here's where I'm pulling the information from http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json

Comment: This confirms my suspicion. The `data` property on the root object (`ChampionData`) should be declared as a dictionary and each named property (champion) becomes an item in the dictionary. As Daniel Mann said, use a single `Champion` class for the items in that dictionary.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils They all appear the same, with the expection of the "Info", "Image" and "Stats" objects, those all apear to be unique for each champion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the comments you need to define a single class that represents all of the Champions. In the example below I have simply renamed the `Ziggs` class in your question to `Champion`:

```
public class Champion
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string blurb { get; set; }
    public Info132 info { get; set; }
    public Image132 image { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
    public string partype { get; set; }
    public Stats132 stats { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to change your `ChampionData` class to use a dictionary to store these objects:

```
public class ChampionData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Champion> Data { get; set; }
}
```

We have used a `Dictionary<string, Champion>` to represent the `data` elements in the JSON. Note the name needs to be `Data` to match the name in the JSON.

The parser will automatically parse the JSON into the dictionary, using the strings as the dictionary key:

```
"data": {
    "Aatrox": { "..." },
    "Ahri": { "..." },
    "Akali": { "..." },
```

So, "Aatrox", "Ahri", "Akali" will be the `string` part of the dictionary (i.e. the `Key`) and the `Champion` part of the dictionary (i.e. the `Value`) will contain all the data that is under each champion in the JSON.

You can now easily access any property of each `Champion` easily. So your `foreach` loop can be:

```
foreach (var c in data.Data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Value.id);
}
```

NOTE: We need to use the `Value` property to access each `Champion` object that is linked to the `Key` part of the `Dictionary`